# TextGenRnn Save Generated Text to File

Tags: python, text, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm having trouble saving the textgenrnn generated text to a file.

Here's my code

```
from textgenrnn import textgenrnn
textgen = textgenrnn()
#after doing all the training work
textgen.generate_to_file('codes_new1.txt', 5)
```

I am supposed to get 5 lines in a file in the current folder. But that does not happen, instead, I get.

```
TypeError: generate_to_file() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I went ahead and checked the source code of textgenrnn and it allows for `**kwargs` as the third argument. Wonder what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it. Added `n=5` instead of `5` and now it works flawlessly